# Why Instruments is showing so many leaks in the following code?

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, instruments

```
- (NSArray *) makeKeyValueArray: (NSArray *) arr
{
    NSMutableArray *result = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int i = 0; i < [arr count]; i++)
    {
        [result addObject:[[KeyValue alloc] initWithData:[arr objectAtIndex:i] :[arr objectAtIndex:i]]];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Instruments is showing 188 leaks in the above code, why is that? can anyone please explain it to me?

Comment: `initWithData::` is an awful method name.   Given the class name, how about `initWithKey:value:`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
- (NSArray *) makeKeyValueArray: (NSArray *) arr
{
    NSMutableArray *result = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int i = 0; i < [arr count]; i++)
    {
        id obj = [[KeyValue alloc] initWithData:[arr objectAtIndex:i] :[arr objectAtIndex:i]]; // obj reference count is now 1, you are the owner
        [result addObject:obj]; //reference count is now 2, the array is also an owner as well as you.
        [obj release];// reference count is now 1, you are not the owner anymore
    }
    return [result autorelease];
}
```

Take a look at [Basic Memory Management Rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH)

> you must relinquish ownership of an object you own

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit? I am not able to understand the concept.

Comment: You are allocating KeyValue, but you are never releasing it. As this answer shows, you have to send a `release` message to the object you created.

Comment: @Parag it is crashing my app now !

Comment: updated your code and explain the reason of the crash. Moreover why did you accept the answer if it is crashing your app?

Comment: @GabrielePetronella because I understood the reason for crash Parag's answer is absolutely correct